# How Do I output only IP's to a txt file with masscan?

Tags: file, sorting, awk, grep, scanning

I am trying to scan specific IP ranges open ports using masscan. When I run the command in terminal the output looks like this:

```
# Ports Scanned: TCP(1;11032-11032) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
```

I would Like to JUST list the IP or Host and have masscan save that in a txt file. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons `grep` has been invented. If you find the regular expression of an IP4 address (can easily be found using a simple Google), you can use this, in combination of `grep -o` : the `-o` makes sure that only the regular expression result is shown, so you get something like:

```
launch_masscan | grep -o "..." // where "..." is the IPv4 regular expression
```

Good luck